# Nifi - FetchSFTP - Move File Failure

Tags: apache-nifi

When running a FetchSFTP processor I am getting the following error:

`FetchSFTP ... Succesfully fetched the content for ... but failed to rename the remote file due to No such file or directory.`

Remote File = `${path}/${filename}`

Completion Strategy = Move File.

Move Destination Directory = `${path}/archive`.

Create Directory has been set to true.

When the processor runs - the archive folder is created successfully but for some reason, the files in `${path}` are not moved. I have no clue how this is not working. Does anyone have any insight on how this may not be set up correctly?

Stack trace from nifi-app.log:

```
2019-09-29 14:16:50,680 INFO [NiFi Web Server-24] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Starting ListSFTP[id=6e2e653d-016d-1000-adc1-0798a2954bf1]
2019-09-29 14:16:50,836 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled ListSFTP[id=6e2e653d-016d-1000-adc1-0798a2954bf1] to run with 1 threads
2019-09-29 14:16:51,023 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-2] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@6cde8b83 // Another save pending = false
2019-09-29 14:16:52,716 INFO [NiFi Web Server-24] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Starting FetchSFTP[id=7d54bd06-016d-1000-1115-ae6da53c9412]
2019-09-29 14:16:52,841 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled FetchSFTP[id=7d54bd06-016d-1000-1115-ae6da53c9412] to run with 1 threads
2019-09-29 14:16:53,263 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-2] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@6cde8b83 // Another save pending = false
2019-09-29 14:16:54,952 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.FetchSFTP FetchSFTP[id=7d54bd06-016d-1000-1115-ae6da53c9412] Successfully fetched the content for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=15c80199-8055-420c-b6ed-b949b3fcfb2a,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1569766614296-1, container=default, section=1], offset=0, length=37],offset=0,name=test.txt,size=37] from [FTP_SITE:FTP_PORT]/[FILE_PATH]/test.txt but failed to rename the remote file due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.util.SFTPTransfer.rename(SFTPTransfer.java:682)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFileTransfer.onTrigger(FetchFileTransfer.java:332)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Update (2019-09-30 21:55)**
I located the rename piece in SFTPTransfer. Updated the error to echo the source and target locations. The source location looks fine... but the target location is the `C:\${path}\${filename}` (running Nifi on Windows Server)
I'm going to see if I can locate where it's being called at see if it can be corrected there.

**Update (2019-10-01 22:00)**
`NiFi V. 1.9.2`
Just updated to 1.10.0 SNAPSHOT
Will see if I can get the standard nar recompiled and get with the results

**Update (2019-10-2 08:25)**
`V.1.10.0-SNAPSHOT` is doing the same thing. Trying to send it to a `C:\` location, at the same time inverting the `/`'s

Comment: Can you show the stracktrace from nifi-app.log that goes with the exception?

Comment: edit - stack trace from nifi-app.log leading up to exception added

Comment: edit 2 - turned on trace logging and was able to pull the exception itself

Comment: This is helpful, what version of NiFi?

Comment: updated post with Nifi version